# how to send cascade data from json to spring controller

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, cascade

I'm trying to send cascade data from json to spring controller. My tables are like below.

```
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int id;
    private A a;
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}

public class A implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Set Bs = new HashSet(0);
}
```

In my jsp code I have made 3 B and I want to save them when I'm saving my A. As you see I have hashset of Bs in my A model.

Here is my question - how can I fill my A with this 3 B's and send A via json then receive it from controller an save A and Bs by one query?

I have already tried this way but I failed:

Here is my json code:

```
var data = {
                'id': 13,
                'name': "a1",
                'B':[{'name':"b1"},{'name':"b2"},{'name':"b3"}],

            };
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: contexPath + A/Save.json,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
.
.
.
}
```

and my controller is :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/Save")
public @ResponseBody
String Save(@Valid @RequestBody A a, BindingResult result) {
    iAService.addA(A);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well for a start, B.name is supposed to be a Double. You're sending "b1" instead. You're also using a raw Set instead of a Set<B>. FIx all the obvious issues, then if it still doesn't work, start by reading the error message you get. Ignoring it won't help.

Comment: "name" is string ,it was a syntax mistake.the question is how can i create a Set<B> in j son.